# How to see BQ query cost before running it?

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

Previously we had BQ Mate and SuperQuery that are no longer working in new UI to check the cost of query.
Is there any free or relatively inexpensive solution that would show cost estimation before running query?

Comment: BQ Mate Author here. Try Goliath - BigQuery IDE, part of Potens.io suite of BigQuery Tools. Among the other very cool features not found in BQ Console, it has cost estimation that you are looking for. Few links to get it - [Google Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/potens-io/potensio), [Potens.io](https://potens.io/), [Potens.io Knowledgebase](https://potensio.zendesk.com/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the links. 999$ a month sounds like a lot. Is there anything suitable for freelancers?

Comment: the price you mentioned is for paid client for 10 licenses for Magnus and Goliath. The free version of Goliath is **free forever** for you to use!

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Pricing Calculator will be the best option to check cost estimation for any google cloud service

`https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs#include_flat-rate_pricing_in_the_pricing_calculator)

> To estimate costs before running a query, you can use one of the following methods:
>
> - Query validator in the Google Cloud console
> - `--dry_run` flag in the bq command-line tool
>   dryRun parameter when submitting a query job using the API
> - The [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/estimate-costs#include_flat-rate_pricing_in_the_pricing_calculator)
> - Client libraries

In your case you have to use the **Query validator** from BQ Console with **Pricing calculator** .When you enter any query in BQ console the Query validator validates the query as well as show how much data will be read at runtime.
You have to enter those details in the **Pricing Calculator** and then you will be able to calculate estimated cost.